# c# xml xpath create attribute if not in document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can I create an attribute if it doesn't exist?

`/Document/Setup/Info/Att/Group[@name='Manu']/osis:Attr[@name='time']/@value`

Some of my documents have the value attribute but most don't.

XML (with time with no value attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="http://www.ns.com/ns/ns">
  <Setup>
    <Info>
      <FilePath>\\computer1\project\E2002307\E2002307.drg</FilePath>
      <Att>
        <Group class="custom" name="Manu" desc="attributes"
            ord="6">
          <Attr num="119" name="xyz" desc="zyx" type="s" ord="1" value="S355">
            <Valid perm="e" max="100"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="120" name="thick" desc="thick." type="r" ord="2" value="5">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="121" name="units" desc="units." type="s" ord="4" value="mm">
            <Valid perm="e" expr="mm" max="80"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="123" name="time" desc="minutes." type="r" ord="24">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="124" name="X" desc="X direction." type="r" ord="11" value="3">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="125" name="Y" desc="Y direction." type="r" ord="12" value="1">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
        </Group>
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML? (`XDocument`/`XmlDocument`/else)

Comment: I'm using XMLDocument and i'm using XPathNavigator to try and get the value  with part.SelectSingleNode("./osis:Att/osis:Group[@name='Manu']/osis:Attr[@name='time']/@value", xmlns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your XPath a bit to make it return `<Attr>` elements that don't have `value` attribute instead of returning the attribute itself :

```
/Document/Setup/Info/Att/Group[@name='Manu']/osis:Attr[@name='time' and not(@value)]
```

Then simply loop through the XPath result and add the attribute as needed :

```
XmlDocument doc;
.....
var query = "/Document/Setup/Info/Att/Group[@name='Manu']/osis:Attr[@name='time' and not(@value)]";
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(query, xmlns);
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("value");
    attr.Value = "foo";        
    node.Attributes.Append(attr);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to write to the document.

Comment: You gotta save the xmldocument object back to file in the end, have you? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var timeAttrs = from grp in doc.Descendants("Group")
                where (string)grp.Attribute("name") == "Manu"
                from attr in grp.Elements("Attr")
                where (string)attr.Attribute("name") == "time" &&
                    attr.Attribute("value") == null
                select attr;

foreach(var attr in timeAttrs)
{
    attr.Add(new XAttribute("value", 1));
}
```